# MediatR IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> errors as The type 'TRequest' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRequest' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, .net, mediatr

I'm using `MediatR` to do Request - Response logging in my application using `IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>`

**Code Sample:**

```cs
internal sealed class AppLoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILogger<AppLoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> _logger;

    public AppLoggingBehavior(ILogger<AppLoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        string requestName = typeof(TRequest).Name;
        string unqiueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string requestJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
        _logger.LogInformation($"Begin Request Id:{unqiueId}, request name:{requestName}, request json:{requestJson}");
        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        var response = await next();
        timer.Stop();
        _logger.LogInformation($"End Request Id:{unqiueId}, request name:{requestName}, total request time:{timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        return response;
    }
}
```

But After upgrading to `Nuget - v10.0.0` I started getting the below compilation error.

> The type 'TRequest' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRequest' in the
> generic type or method 'IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>'. There
> is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TRequest'
> to 'MediatR.IRequest'

I managed to find the [porting guide](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Migration-Guide-9.x-to-10.0) from official `MediatR` repo. But couldn't find any examples.

Am I missing something else, Please can anyone assist me on this?

Comment: The porting guide is very obvious about what should be done, just add the green text from the porting guide (`where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>`) to your class declaration making your entire class declaration `internal sealed class AppLoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>`

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I misunderstood the example in porting guide as `git` diff.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need to specify the type of your `TRequest` parameter in your abstract class as well. It has to be at least specific as the parameter in the interface you're trying to implement.

```
internal sealed class AppLoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : MediatR.IRequest<TResponse> // <- this is the part you're missing
{
    // rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: In v12 this has been reverted to `where TRequest : notnull`. See [the migration guide](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Migration-Guide-11.x-to-12.0#rolling-back-generic-constraints).

Answer (score 2):

According to the Github docs, this is what is required
https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Migration-Guide-9.x-to-10.0

where TRequest : IRequest

Comment: aaaaaand, in V12 this has been reverted....